# MPI Send Recv deadlock

Tags: mpi, deadlock

I write programs using MPI and I have an access to two different clusters. I am not good in system administration, so I can not tell anything about software, OS, compilers which are used there. But, on one machine I have an deadlock using such code:

```
#include "mpi.h"
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

  int rank, numprocs;
  MPI_Status status;

  MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numprocs);

  int x = rank;

  if (rank == 0) {
      for (int i=0; i<numprocs; ++i)
          MPI_Send(&x, 1, MPI_INT, i, 100500, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
  }
  MPI_Recv(&x, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 100500, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);

  MPI_Finalize();
  return 0;
}
```

The error message is related:

```
Fatal error in MPI_Send: Other MPI error, error stack:
MPI_Send(184): MPI_Send(buf=0x7fffffffceb0, count=1, MPI_INT, dest=0, tag=100500, MPI_COMM_WORLD) failed
MPID_Send(54): DEADLOCK: attempting to send a message to the local process without a prior matching receive
```

Why is that so? I can't understand, why does it happen on one machine, but doesn't happen on another?

Answer (score 1):

`MPI_Send` is a blocking operation. It may not complete until a matching receive is posted. In your case `rank` 0 is trying to send a message to itself before having posted a matching receive. If you must do something like this you would replace `MPI_Send` with MPI_Isend`(+`MPI_Wait...` after the receive). But you might as well just not make him send a message to itself.

The proper thing to use in your case is `MPI_Bcast`.

Comment: Thank you, Zulan, but in my case I can't use MPI_Bcast (code related is just an example of my reallife program).

Comment: MPI provides many different collective operations. It is generally preferred to use those whenever applicable. I would recommend you show a closer example to the communication pattern of your application.

Answer (score 1):

Since rank 0 already has the correct value of `x`, you do not need to send it in a message. This means that in the loop you should skip sending to rank 0 and instead start from rank 1:

```c
if (rank == 0) {
    for (int i=1; i<numprocs; ++i)
        MPI_Send(&x, 1, MPI_INT, i, 100500, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
}
MPI_Recv(&x, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 100500, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
```

Now rank 0 won't try to talk to itself, but since the receive is outside the conditional, it will still try to receive a message from itself. The solution is to simply make the receive the alternative branch:

```c
if (rank == 0) {
    for (int i=1; i<numprocs; ++i)
        MPI_Send(&x, 1, MPI_INT, i, 100500, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
}
else
    MPI_Recv(&x, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 100500, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
```

Another more involved solution is to use non-blocking operations to post the receive before the send operation:

```c
MPI_Request req;

MPI_Irecv(&x, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 100500, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &req);
if (rank == 0) {
    int xx = x;
    for (int i=0; i<numprocs; ++i)
        MPI_Send(&xx, 1, MPI_INT, i, 100500, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
}
MPI_Wait(&req, &status);
```

Now rank 0 will not block in `MPI_Send` as there is already a matching receive posted earlier. In all other ranks `MPI_Irecv` will be immediately followed by `MPI_Wait`, which is equivalent to a blocking receive (`MPI_Recv`). Note that the value of `x` is copied to a different variable inside the conditional as simultaneously sending from and receiving into the same memory location is forbidden by the MPI standard for obvious correctness reasons.